# Update OpenGL libraries on windows

Tags: windows, opengl

I'm using a 3rd party DLL which uses OpenGL. Right now that 3rd party does not work correctly as the display does not refresh correctly. I came to suspect that the OpenGL library isn't correctly installed or may be outdated.

Is there a way to update the OpenGL library on windows? Is there like an official site which will hold the correct opengl.dll file or something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the OpenGL libraries are just part of the drivers that ship with your graphics card.  Upgrading your graphics drivers should upgrade your OpenGL stuff to the latest your card supports.

Answer (score 3):

OpenGL should be up to date on Windows.

However, if you are getting display/refresh problems, and they're only occuring on windows, this is most likely an issue with your graphics driver.

Try updating to your latest OpenGL graphics driver.  This fixes many OpenGL issues on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

opengl.dll is part of your display card driver. Windows comes with a default opengl.dll that offers very little acceleration. Re installing the graphics card driver or upgrading to the latest version should take care of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL is implemented in the graphics driver. If you want to use the latest OpenGL version as a developer you download and use GLEW (http://glew.sourceforge.net/) as a normal library. This will give you access to cross platform OpenGL 4.1 or whatever version your card supports.